# Adding text between the title of nomenclature and the start of the list

Tags: nomenclature

It is my first time to use the nomencl package. I was wondering if there is a way to add text between the title of nomenclature and the first item on the list?

Many thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the best you have managed to produce. It will be much easier for us to help you with compilable code to build upon.

Answer (score 4):

I have found the solution, and I am posting it here for those who might have the same question.

I have redefined the macro `\nompreamble` before `\begin{document}` as follows:

```
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{YOUR TEXT}
```