# Nomencl package - line of text before symbols?

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

I'm using the nomencl package to create a nomenclature. As a MWE i have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\newcommand\Nomenclature[3][X]{\nomenclature[#1#3]{#2}{#3}}

\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\large\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Acronyms}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{R}{Roman Symbols}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{G}{Greek Symbols}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{M}{Molecules}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{X}{Other Symbols}{}}}}}]%
  }


\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

Other variables may appear. 

\Nomenclature[G]{$\omega$}{Absolute Frequency}
\Nomenclature[G]{$f$}{Frequency}
\Nomenclature[M]{HOffffA}{Acetic acid}
\Nomenclature[M]{Al}{Aluminium}
\Nomenclature[A]{ASTM}{American Standard Testing Machine}
\Nomenclature[X]{foo2}{foo2}
\Nomenclature{foo1}{foo1}

\printnomenclature[5cm]


\end{document}
```

This produces the text:

[image]

However, how can i get the line 'Other variables may appear.' to appear under the Nomenclature title?

Also, how can I increase the vertical spacing between the Nomenclature title (and the smaller sub titles like Greek symbols etc) and the first entries? It's very bunched at the moment. The vertical spacing between the entries seems okay, it's just the spacing between the titles and first entries.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202561/adding-text-between-the-title-of-nomenclature-and-the-start-of-the-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add something after the title, as well as control the title spacing with the definition of `\nompreamble`.

add

```
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{Other variables may appear.\vspace{0.75em}}
```

To your preamble. You can, of course, change the size  of `\vspace` to anything you want.